# Improve performance of git operations on compressed binary files

Tags: git

I'm using git to manage a relatively large set of binary files. It's a mix of a few thousand `eps`, `png`, `jpg`, `gif`, `pdf` files and a few small text files totaling over 53GB. I find that git is kind of slow. Sure, lots of folks say "don't use git" and that's fine.

I've ready about using `.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes` to set git to not do a delta on these files with syntax like:

```
*.jpg -delta
```

However, I haven't read exactly where that needs to go. Two questions:

1. Add that to the `.gitattributes` file that is checked into the repository?
2. Would it help to have it in the `.git/info/attributes/` in my central repository?

My experience is that performance is pretty slow for both new clones of this repository AND for commits of many files and/or large files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`gitattributes(5)`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html):

> If you wish to affect only a single repository (i.e., to assign attributes to files that are particular to one user’s workflow for that repository), then attributes should be placed in the $GIT_DIR/info/attributes file. Attributes which should be version-controlled and distributed to other repositories (i.e., attributes of interest to all users) should go into .gitattributes files.

I.e., your option (1).

Comment: That is helpful. Can you answer the second question, whether having it in the central repository's .git/info/attributes would be helpful (e.g. for new clones)?

Comment: @greggles: never mind previous comment, I was wrong. If the remote does not have a `.git/info/attributes`, or one that does not explicitly state `*.jpg delta`, then adding a `.gitattributes` should suffice.